# Download a EXCEL file using React+ SpringBoot

Tags: java, excel, spring, reactjs, spring-boot

I am facing a new problem: I want to download EXCEL file which I fetch using a GET request in react environment.

The backend controller is this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/api/tickets/xls")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public void getEntitiesXLS(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{

        List<Ticket> data = ticketRepository.findAll();    
        try(
                Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        ){
            createExcel(workbook, data )

            response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"tickets.xlsx\"");
            workbook.write(response.getOutputStream());
        }
    }
```

And the client side part made in react:

```
import FileSaver from 'file-saver'

[...]

downloadTickets = () =>{
    const { dispatchGetXLS, dispatchThrowError } = this.props
    const { reduxApi } = this.context  

    dispatchGetXLS(reduxApi, (err,data)=>{
      if(err){
        dispatchThrowError(err)
        return
      }

      console.log(data) // HERE I SEE AN OUTPUT
      const blob = new Blob([data], {type:'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'})
      console.log(blob)
      FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "tickets.xlsx")
    })
  }
```

When I open my .xlsx file with notepad it shows only a line: 
    [object    object]

end Blog size is 15

what is wrong?

Comment: Hi, am new to React world,  can you post ReactJS complete logic

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem!
in react you must set

const blob = new Blob([data.data], {type:'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'})

now blob size is 5896 but i can't see the excel file yet. Excel says that it seems to be damaged